# Adding a column of repeating values to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some quarter level data for finance deals, so a pretty big dataset. I now want to add the following values to a new column repeated over and over:

```
[-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

The column should then look something like this:

```
A
-12
-11
-10
...
11
12
-12
-11
...
11
12
```

So basically just that list repeating over and over until the last row of my Dataframe. I hope this question is clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
N = len(df)
df['A'] = pd.Series(np.tile(lst, N//len(lst))).iloc[:N]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, the values aren't repeating as I want them to. They are all jumbled up and seem to follow no particular pattern. I also get this message: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Nevermind, your solution worked. I forgot to reindex my dataframe thats is why the numbers werent repeating as I wanted them to. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) will repeat an iterator indefinitely, and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) takes only the leading portion.

```
pd.Series(list(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(range(-12,13)), len(df))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy` `place`

```
a=np.zeros(len(data_file))
np.place(a,a>=0,np.array([1,2]))
a
Out[526]: array([1., 2., 1., 2.])
```